# tkinter button wont release after click

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to python development and am currently building a gui using tkinter.

My button works as expected when clicked, opens another window displays face bounding boxes, however when I close the faces window and return to the buttons main window, the button still displays as clicked (pressed/sunken) and I cannot click any other buttons or close the window.

How do I release the button after it is clicked?

```
def btn1():
    os.system("python App.py group.jpg")

button1 = Button(window, text = "Button 1", command=btn1).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: The button isn't going to go back to normal until its `command=` function returns - and apparently the program you're launching doesn't exit promptly when you close its window.  One possibility would be to use the `subprocess` module to launch the other program without waiting for it to complete - but note that this would allow you to launch multiple instances of the program.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into subprocess.  Is it possible to add a return statement to the function definition def btn1(): that would release the button ???

Comment: The function automatically returns after `os.system()` returns, but that doesn't happen until the launched program finishes.  (And a `return` before that line would mean that the program never gets launched.)  That's why I'm suggesting using something other than `os.system()`.

Comment: Ive implemented subprocess as follows:

def btn1():
facesDetect = subprocess.run(["python", "App.py", "group.jpg"])

It runs the command successfully but however as with os.system, the button remains pressed down.  I tried adding a quit() at the end of the APP.py file but that did not seem to help.  I don't understand why the command is not completing and button is not releasing as the command executes and displays accordingly and there is no other code in the App.py file that requires running..  Can I avoid this issue if I use another GUI library instead of tinkter?

Comment: You'd want to use something like `subprocess.Popen()` that doesn't wait for the process to finish (although figuring out why the other program isn't quitting when it should would be a good idea in any case).  I don't think a different GUI library would behave any differently here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(SOLUTION)
I discovered that the last line of the App.py script was: cv2.waitKey(0)
The user must hit "Enter" in-order for the commmand/waitKey to terminate.
Closing the window using the 'X' on the window toolbar, does close the window but does not terminate the command and leaves the button in a pressed-state.

I have amended this value to specific time parameter 2500 i.e. 2500 milliseconds so no user involvement is required.  Although as stated, simply pressing 'enter/return' terminates the command and releases the button.

To confirm, this works for both os.system and subprocess.

Hope this helps save others sometime, and thanks to everyone for your help.